# Downloaded theme not functional

Tags: theme, installation

I have downloaded a theme. The folder contains *app, js, media* and *skin* folders.
I have disabled and flushed all the caches. Then I have copied the theme's folders to Magento root (located in local virtual host 'magento.local') overwriting the existing folders. That caused the site to stop working.
Later, I started to manually copy the files from the theme folders to the corresponding Magento locations so as not to delete any of the existing files and I have put down my theme's name in all of the the 'System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes' inputs. However the site still has the default look.

I would say, that I should delete some of the default folders in the *app, js, media* or *skin* folders but I'm not sure which ones.

Is there any way some of you could help my having these information, please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find corresponding folders in Magento's root for app, skin, js and media.

Theme layout files (app) go in app/design/frontend/THEME_NAME

Skin files (skin) go in skin/frontend/THEME_NAME

The js and media files have their own folders in Magento's root.

Once you have your theme files in place, you should be able to select the theme (THEME_NAME) from admin.

Do NOT delete the base and default theme folders, as these are what Magento falls back on if you have a missing file in your custom theme.

Answer (score 1):

Where have you put the theme and assets. The theme should be app/design/frontend/ and assets (JS) in skin/frontend/package

Then you can set the design package via the admin.

Comment: You should put your comments in the comments and not the answers section since you technically asked them a followup question.